# I have 2 tables ( unit , user ) each user can have many units, I am trying to return each user with it all units as json , using laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to do this:

```
$unitsPayments = Unit::leftJoin('uf_user', 'uf_unit.owner', '=', 'uf_user.id') 
->select('uf_unit.code','uf_user.display_name','uf_unit.neighborhood',
         'uf_unit.id AS unit_id','uf_unit.owner AS unit_owner')->get();
```

but it return the data separated like this.
I need to have first user and all it unit inside it

so at the end I will only have 2 nodes for users and each node will have 2 unit nodes

This is current JSON:

```
[
    {
        "code": "121",
        "display_name": "zal",
        "neighborhood": "wan",
        "unit_id": 49,
        "unit_owner": 17
    },
    {
        "code": "47",
        "display_name": "Ahmad",
        "neighborhood": "aim",
        "unit_id": 63,
        "unit_owner": 2
    },
    {
        "code": "21",
        "display_name": "Ahmad",
        "neighborhood": "wan",
        "unit_id": 64,
        "unit_owner": 2
    },
    {
        "code": "102",
        "display_name": "zal",
        "neighborhood": "war",
        "unit_id": 65,
        "unit_owner": 17
    }
]
```

and this is how I need the data to look like:

```
[{
        "display_name": "zal",
        "unit_owner": 17,
        "units": {
            "code": "102",
            "neighborhood": "war",
            "unit_id": 65
        } {
            "code": "121",
            "neighborhood": "wan",
            "unit_id": 49
        }
    },
    {
        "display_name": "Ahmad",
        "unit_owner": 2,
        "units": {
            "code": "47",
            "neighborhood": "aim",
            "unit_id": 63,
        } {
            "code": "21",
            "neighborhood": "wan",
            "unit_id": 64,
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add json as code not as an image.

Comment: You also need to add _both_ the current and expected output. Your image isn't clear enough.

Comment: Why don't you use hasMany relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should set up proper relationships using Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Your code will look like this:

```
$unitsPayments = User::with('units')->get();
```

And in User class:

```
class User extends Model {
  public function units(){
    return $this->hasMany(Unit::class, 'owner');
  }
}
```